# Offsetting top left data from a range to the first two columns with data

Tags: vba, for-loop, offset

I am still pretty new at VBA and I am having trouble with using an offset range function to loop through my code and move data the top left of each range in my report to the left two columns.

For example, my original report looks like:

```
4101     Canada
GJ002568    



4102     Mexico
GJ002566    
GJ002566    



4103     Newcastle
GJ002567    
00001626    
00001634
```

I need it to be formatted like this:

```
 4101     Canada     GJ002568


 4102     Mexico     GJ002566
 4102     Mexico     GJ002566


 4103     Newcastle  GJ002567
 4103     Newcastle  00001626
 4103     Newcastle  00001634
```

The rows in the sheet must be dynamic because I won't always know the length and the ranges would also need to be as well because there are different amounts in each one. I have written a macro to help assist with writing the name to the last row but it do what I need it to do.

```
Sub WriteNames()
Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row 'This three references the last row in column B

    Dim i As Long

    For i = 2 To LastRow   'This starts at 2 because the first row is a header
        If Cells(i, 1).Value = ""
        Cells(i, 1).Value = Cells(i - 1, 1).Value  'The neg one ref cell above
    Next i
End Sub
```

Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: is this a one-time need or something that needs to be automated for regular use?  Also, where is this data coming from and how's it being imported?  It may be easier to lay out the data properly while it's being imported.

Comment: Hi, this is a report that is used on a regular basis actually and it comes from an Australian accounting system that displays GL detail activity.  I can try to manipulate the report but for some reason the top line always displays this way making it very time consuming to format so this automation would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try storing the primary keys in an array.

```
Sub writeNames()
    Dim i As Long, lr As Long, arr() As Variant
    With Worksheets("sheet")
        lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 2 To lr
            If CBool(Len(.Cells(i, "A").Value)) And CBool(Len(.Cells(i, "B").Value)) Then
                arr = .Cells(i, "A").Resize(1, 2).Value
                .Cells(i, "A").Resize(1, 2).ClearContents
            ElseIf CBool(Len(.Cells(i, "A").Value)) Then
                .Cells(i, "C").NumberFormat = "@"
                .Cells(i, "C") = .Cells(i, "A").Value
                .Cells(i, "A").Resize(1, 2) = arr
            End If
        Next i
        With .Cells(2, "A").Resize(lr, 3)
            .Sort Key1:=.Cells(1), Order1:=xlAscending, _
                  Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlNo
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

I've used rudimentary sorting to remove 'dead' rows and formatted column C as text to preserve leading zeroes on some entries.

[image]

original data

[image]

Comment: Sorry this did not work for me, it deleted all of my lines and only left me with the top row.

Comment: Perhaps I guessed wrong as to the original data layout. See above.